# Quiero que el Activity se actualice después de que se cierre el dialogfragment. ¿Cómo puedo lograrlo?

Tags: android-fragment, activity, fragment, xamarin.android, diálogo

Tengo 1 Activity, del cual invoco un DialogFragment, cómo puedo lograr que se refresque mi Activityal cerrar el DialogFragment, es que en mi Activity tengo un listview que se tiene que refrescar al cerrar el DialogFragment, alguna idea, éste es mi código.

Activity:

```
private void LstProveedores_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            EditText et = new EditText(this);
            alert.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.StatSysUploadDone);
            alert.SetTitle("Actualizar/Eliminar");
            alert.SetPositiveButton("Actualizar ", (senderAlert, args) =>
            {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactions = 
                FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                ProveedorPopUp pop = new ProveedorPopUp();
                pop.Show(fragmentTransactions, "dialog fragments");

            });

            alert.SetNegativeButton("Eliminar", (senderAlert, args) =>
            {

            });

            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                alert.Show();
            });
        }
```

DialogFragment:

```
 private void BtnGuardarProveedo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (txtRazonSocial.Text == string.Empty || txtNombreCorto.Text == string.Empty || txtRFC.Text == string.Empty || txtPlazoDias.Text == string.Empty || txtNombreContacto.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "Los campos, Razón Socia, Nombre Corto, RFC, Plazo Días,y Nombre Contacto son obligatorios", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    prove.Borrado = false;
                    prove.RazonSocial = txtRazonSocial.Text.ToUpper();
                    prove.NombreCorto = txtNombreCorto.Text.ToUpper();
                    prove.RFC = txtRFC.Text.ToUpper();
                    prove.CalleNumero = txtCalleNumero.Text.ToUpper();
                    prove.Colonia = txtColonia.Text.ToUpper();
                    prove.Ciudad = txtCiudad.Text.ToUpper();
                    prove.Estado = txtEstado.Text.ToUpper();
                    prove.CodigoPostal = int.Parse(txtCodigoPostal.Text);
                    prove.Pais = txtPais.Text.ToUpper();
                    prove.Telefono1 = (txtTelefono1.Text).ToUpper();
                    prove.Telefono2 =(txtTelefono2.Text).ToUpper();
                    prove.Email = txtEmail.Text.ToUpper();
                    prove.NombreContacto = txtNombreContacto.Text.ToUpper();
                    prove.PlazoDias = int.Parse(txtPlazoDias.Text);
                    prove.Observaciones = txtObservaciones.Text.ToUpper();
                    if (func.InsertProveedor(prove) == 1)
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "Proveedor registrado", ToastLength.Long).Show() ;
                        LimpiarControles();
                        Dismiss();
///
Aquí quiero que se ejecute el refresh del activity, cuando se cierre el dialog
///

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "La razón social ya se encuentra registrada, intente con otra", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long);
        }
    }
```

¿Hay manera que cuando se ejecute el Insert en el DialogFragment, y se cierre el dialogfragment con el Dismiss(); se pueda refrescar el Activity?

Intenté algo cómo ésto pero no me funciono, una instancia del activity y usar el método Recreate(); pero no funciona.

Proveedores activity = new Proveedores();
 activity.Recreate();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crea una interfaz en el `DialogFragment` he implementala en el `activity`.

#### DialogFragment

```
public class Dialogo extends DialogFragment {

// ...

    // Se crea la interfaz
    inteface Actualizar {
        public void actualizarActividad();
    }

    Actualizar actualizar;

// ...

    private void BtnGuardarProveedo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtRazonSocial.Text == string.Empty || txtNombreCorto.Text == string.Empty || txtRFC.Text == string.Empty || txtPlazoDias.Text == string.Empty || txtNombreContacto.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "Los campos, Razón Socia, Nombre Corto, RFC, Plazo Días,y Nombre Contacto son obligatorios", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                prove.Borrado = false;
                prove.RazonSocial = txtRazonSocial.Text.ToUpper();
                prove.NombreCorto = txtNombreCorto.Text.ToUpper();
                prove.RFC = txtRFC.Text.ToUpper();
                prove.CalleNumero = txtCalleNumero.Text.ToUpper();
                prove.Colonia = txtColonia.Text.ToUpper();
                prove.Ciudad = txtCiudad.Text.ToUpper();
                prove.Estado = txtEstado.Text.ToUpper();
                prove.CodigoPostal = int.Parse(txtCodigoPostal.Text);
                prove.Pais = txtPais.Text.ToUpper();
                prove.Telefono1 = (txtTelefono1.Text).ToUpper();
                prove.Telefono2 =(txtTelefono2.Text).ToUpper();
                prove.Email = txtEmail.Text.ToUpper();
                prove.NombreContacto = txtNombreContacto.Text.ToUpper();
                prove.PlazoDias = int.Parse(txtPlazoDias.Text);
                prove.Observaciones = txtObservaciones.Text.ToUpper();
                if (func.InsertProveedor(prove) == 1)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "Proveedor registrado", ToastLength.Long).Show() ;
                    LimpiarControles();
                    Dismiss();

                    // llamas el metodo de la interfaz que se implementa en la actividad
                    actualizar.actualizarActividad();

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "La razón social ya se encuentra registrada, intente con otra", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Actividad

```
public class Actividad extents Activity implement Dialogo.Actualizar {

    // ...      
    @Override
    public void actualizaActividad() {

        // Aqui colocas el codigo para actualizar tu ListView

    }
    // ...

}
```